# C# .NET - Reactive extensions error

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I've a C# 4.0 class library projet in which I've referenced Reactive extensions dlls(2.2.5 version).
I'm getting compilation errors as mentioned below.Could you advise please?

C# code:

```
var observable = System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.Empty<bool>();

            foreach (var modelParam in modelParams)
                observable = observable.Merge(modelParam.ObservePropertyChanged(p => p.IsDirty).Where(p => p));
```

### *Error  522 'System.IObservable' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IObservable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Error   508 'System.IObservable' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IObservable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import the namespace that defines the extension method:

```
using System.Reactive.Linq;
```